# Grid : While open FF for perticular node getting an error GridConfigurationException: -browser format browserName-firefox doesn't follow that format

Tags: selenium-grid

I am new to working with Selenium Grid.
i tried to open the browser in FF for perticular node (5556) for the same followed the below steps

1. To launch the hub

> java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0.jar -role hub

1. to open the browser in FF for particular node (5556)

> ```
> java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0.jar -role webdriver -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -port 5556  -browser  browserName-firefox
> ```

It throws an error

```
Aug 29, 2013 4:28:56 AM org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher main
INFO: Launching a selenium grid node
Aug 29, 2013 4:28:56 AM org.openqa.grid.common.RegistrationRequest addCapability
FromString
INFO: Adding browserName-firefox
Error building the config :-browser format is key1=value1,key2=value2 browserNam
e-firefox doesn't follow that format.
Usage :
  -hubConfig:
    (hub) a JSON file following grid2 format that defines the hub
      properties.

  -nodeTimeout:
    (node) <XXXX>  the timeout in seconds before the hub
      automatically ends a test that hasn't had any activity in the
      last X seconds. The browser will be released for another test to
      use. This typically takes care of the client crashes.

  -throwOnCapabilityNotPresent:
    (hub) <true | false> default to true. If true, the hub will
      reject test requests right away if no proxy is currently
      registered that can host that capability.Set it to false to have
      the request queued until a node supporting the capability is
      added to the grid.

  -maxSession:
    (node) max number of tests that can run at the same time on the
      node, independently of the browser used.

  -hub:
    (node) <http://localhost:4444/grid/register> : the url that will
      be used to post the registration request. This option takes
      precedence over -hubHost and -hubPort options.

  -hubPort:
    (node) <xxxx> : the port listened by a hub the registration
      request should be sent to. Default to 4444. Option -hub takes
      precedence over this option.

  -registerCycle:
    (node) how often in ms the node will try to register itself
      again.Allow to restart the hub without having to restart the
      nodes.

  -capabilityMatcher:
    (hub) a class implementing the CapabilityMatcher interface.
      Defaults to
      org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.DefaultCapabilityMatcher. Specify
      the logic the hub will follow to define if a request can be
      assigned to a node.Change this class if you want to have the
      matching process use regular expression instead of exact match
      for the version of the browser for instance. All the nodes of a
      grid instance will use the same matcher, defined by the registry.

  -nodeStatusCheckTimeout:
    (node) in ms. Connection and socket timeout which is used for
      node alive check.

  -port:
    (hub & node) <xxxx> : the port the remote/hub will listen on.
      Default to 4444.

  -hubHost:
    (node) <IP | hostname> : the host address of a hub the
      registration request should be sent to. Default to localhost.
      Option -hub takes precedence over this option.

  -newSessionWaitTimeout:
    (hub) <XXXX>. Default to no timeout ( -1 ) the time in ms after
      which a new test waiting for a node to become available will time
      out.When that happens, the test will throw an exception before
      starting a browser.

  -nodePolling:
    (node) in ms. Interval between alive checks of node how often the
      hub checks if the node is still alive.

  -host:
    (hub & node)  <IP | hostname> : usually not needed and determined
      automatically. For exotic network configuration, network with
      VPN, specifying the host might be necessary.

  -downPollingLimit:
    (node) node is marked as down after downPollingLimit alive
      checks.

  -unregisterIfStillDownAfter:
    (node) in ms. If the node remains down for more than
      unregisterIfStillDownAfter millisec, it will disappear from the
      hub.Default is 1min.

  -cleanupCycle:
    (node) <XXXX> in ms. How often a proxy will check for timed out
      thread.

  -nodeConfig:
    (node) a JSON file following grid2 format that defines the node
      properties.

  -prioritizer:
    (hub) a class implementing the Prioritizer interface. Default to
      null ( no priority = FIFO ).Specify a custom prioritizer if you
      need the grid to process the tests from the CI, or the IE tests
      first for instance.

  -servlets:
    (hub & node) <com.mycompany.MyServlet,com.mycompany.MyServlet2>
      to register a new servlet on the hub/node. The servlet will
      accessible under the path  /grid/admin/MyServlet
      /grid/admin/MyServlet2

  -proxy:
    (node) the class that will be used to represent the node. By
      default org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy.

  -browserTimeout:
    (hub/node) The timeout in seconds a browser can hang

  -grid1Yml:
    (hub) a YML file following grid1 format.

  -role:
    <hub|node> (default is no grid, just run an RC/webdriver server).
      When launching a node, the parameters will be forwarded to the
      server on the node, so you can use something like -role node
      -trustAllSSLCertificates.  In that case, the SeleniumServer will
      be launch with the trustallSSLCertificates option.

org.openqa.grid.common.exception.GridConfigurationException: -browser format is
key1=value1,key2=value2 browserName-firefox doesn't follow that format.
        at org.openqa.grid.common.RegistrationRequest.addCapabilityFromString(Re
gistrationRequest.java:522)
        at org.openqa.grid.common.RegistrationRequest.loadFromCommandLine(Regist
rationRequest.java:505)
        at org.openqa.grid.common.RegistrationRequest.build(RegistrationRequest.
java:392)
        at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher.main(GridLauncher.java:109)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message clearly tells you what the problem is:

```
-browser format is key1=value1,key2=value2 browserName-firefox doesn't follow that format.
```

Change the browserName parameter to **browserName=firefox**.

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0.jar -role webdriver -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -port 5556  -browser  browserName=firefox
```